# React Native & Relay, compatibility. Official way to get them to work together?

Tags: react-native, relay

Preface: I am new to Javascript, Babel and React-Native.

I have been developing my app using the TodoMVC example from the relay source. I was wondering if it's possible to get React-Native + Relay to work together easily?

I setup my babelRelayPlugin and added it to my .babelrc. I installed the npm packages for "react-relay":"^0.7.3" and "babel-relay-plugin": "^0.7.3" but after running "npm install" and "react-native start" I either get an error saying "Unrecognized module 'react-relay'" OR "Relay is not defined".

From reading this thread and looking at the last comment ( https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/26#issuecomment-194570137 ) it looks like at the moment I should just use TodoMVC as my base for new React-Native + Relay projects.

Is this correct?

Here is my .babelrc

```
{
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "passPerPreset": true,
      "presets": [
        {
          "plugins": [
            "./plugins/babelRelayPlugin"
          ]
        },
        "react-native"
      ]
    },
    "server": {
      "plugins": [
        "./plugins/babelRelayPlugin"
      ],
      "presets": [
        "es2015",
        "stage-0"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "testApp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean:babelrc": "find ./node_modules -name react-packager -prune -o -name '.babelrc' -print | xargs rm -f",
    "postinstall": "npm run clean:babelrc",
    "start": "BABEL_ENV=server babel-node ./server.js",
    "update-schema": "babel-node ./scripts/updateSchema.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^1.5.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-relay-plugin": "^0.7.3",
    "express": "4.13.4",
    "express-graphql": "0.4.9",
    "graphql": "0.4.17",
    "graphql-relay": "0.3.6",
    "moment": "^2.12.0",
    "node-fetch": "^1.4.1",
    "react": "^0.14.5",
    "react-native": "^0.22.2",
    "react-native-animatable": "^0.5.2",
    "react-native-aws3": "0.0.1",
    "react-native-camera": "git+https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera.git",
    "react-native-console-panel": "0.0.7",
    "react-native-contacts": "^0.2.3",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "0.0.6",
    "react-relay": "^0.7.3",
    "sync-request": "^3.0.0",
    "uuid-v4": "^0.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.6.4",
    "flow-bin": "^0.22.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "npm": ">=3"
  }
}
```

Comment: With latest React Native (0.22) and Relay (0.7.3) releases it's now possible to use them together out of the box. Could you share you your .babelrc and package.json? Also the place where you import react-relay.

Comment: Here is example project I've built with React Native and Relay, maybe this will provide you with some reference. https://github.com/reindexio/reindex-examples/tree/master/react-native-gallery

Comment: @freiksenet just updated my post with babelrc and package.json. Thank's for providing your package I will take a look at your setup.

Comment: I copied over your .babelrc and package.json and merged it with mine. I still get this error 2016-04-06 16:30:38.342 [fatal][tid:com.facebook.React.RCTExceptionsManagerQueue] Unhandled JS Exception: Requiring unknown module "react-relay". If you are sure the module is there, try restarting the packager or running "npm install".

Comment: That doesn't look like a React Native package.json to me. You could try initializing react native with "react-native init", so that it can bootstrap native applications for you.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the issue. I added   "babel-core": "^6.7.6" as a dev dependency. Removed all the scripts and cloned the project from git to a new folder. Everything runs perfectly now!